# Html.EditorFor in an MVCContrib PortableArea

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib, portable-areas

I am trying to use Html.EditorFor in a Portable Area (i.e. so create and edit use the same form), but it doesn't seem to working (fine when it is not in the Portable Area though). In the page, I just have:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MySite.Models.DocumentType>" %>
...
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model, new { }) %>
```

Then in the 'EditorTemplates' sub folder I have my editor code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MySite.Models.DocumentType>" %>
...
```

However, it doesn't seem to be using it to render the editor.